# Kendo child grid call jquery function row template in MVC, it's work in jquery but how it's work in MVC grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm facing kendo child grid columns template issue can anyone help to find out the problem,

below my code for grid and Child grid

https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/detailtemplate

```
// Parent grid code
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="table-responsive">
         @(Html.Kendo().Grid<VehicleMain>()
         .Name("VehicleGrid")
         .NoRecords("No Record Found.")
         .Columns(columns =>
         {                                                                                                       
         columns.Bound(e => e.VehAssetNo).Title("ASSET NO").Width("11%");
         columns.Bound(e => e.BranchCode).Title("Branch").Width("11%");        
         );
         })         
         .Sortable()
         .Filterable()
         .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")         
         .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
         .Ajax()        
         .Read(read => read.Action("GetVehicleMainBySearch", "VehicleMain", new { area = "" }))        
         .Model(VehicleMain => VehicleMain.Id(x => x.VehId))
         )
         )
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

//Child grid code here I'm facing issue to binding jquery function in the row `template`

```
<script id="template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<VehicleSub>()
.Name("grid_#=VehId#") // template expression, to be evaluated in the master context
.NoRecords("No Record Found.")
.Columns(columns =>
{
columns.Bound(o => o.JobType).Title("Job Type").Width("12%");
columns.Bound(o => o.VehSubDatePerformed).Title("Date Performed").Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Width("12%");
columns.Bound(o => o.VehSubAmountSpent).Title("Amount Spent").Width("16%");
columns.Bound(o => o.VehSubODO).Title("ODO READING").Width("20%");
columns.Bound(o => o.VehSubNote).Title("Note").Width("20%");
})
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
.Ajax()
.PageSize(Constant.KendoDefaultPageSize)
.ServerOperation(false)
.Read(read => read.Action("GetVehicleSubHistory", "VehicleMain", new { VehId = "#=VehId#" }))
)
.ToClientTemplate()
)
</script>
```

Just want to call this function here the jquery code

```
function odoTotal() {
    var gridVehIddata = dataSource.data();
    var VehSubODOfirst = 0;
    var VehSubODOlast = 0;
    var datalength = (gridVehIddata.length) - 1;
    VehSubODOfirst = gridVehIddata[0].VehSubODO;
    VehSubODOlast = gridVehIddata[datalength].VehSubODO;

    return VehSubODOfirst - VehSubODOlast;
}
```

Above function, I want to call in the Child grid with the `VehSubODO` column filed but every time just function name print, not function execute if I work with jquery kendo grid then it's work can anyone suggest how can I solve this.

I have tried this solution but not work.

`columns.Bound(o => o.VehSubODO).Title("ODO READING").Width("20%").FooterTemplate("odoTotal()");`

`columns.Bound(o => o.VehSubODO).Title("ODO READING").Width("20%").ClientFooterTemplate("odoTotal()");`

In both cases, I gotten the same result as mention in the below image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the call to the js function within the ClientFooterTemplate, like so:

```
columns.Bound(o => o.VehSubODO).Title("ODO 
READING").Width("20%").ClientFooterTemplate("#= odoTotal()#");
```

Also, you may need to escape the # characters since you want that javascript function called within the child grid scope ([more info here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-child-properties-in-child-template?_ga=2.15774261.225357112.1597603015-678502017.1597603015)) like so:

```
columns.Bound(o => o.VehSubODO).Title("ODO 
READING").Width("20%").ClientFooterTemplate("\\#= odoTotal()\\#");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer  but it's not working in child grid ):

Comment: @jishansiddique are you getting an error? If so, what is it? Also, you may need to escape the # characters - I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: I'm not getting error,sure I'll check this code and get back to you.